# How do I get the button working (Cocoa/NSButton)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I have a code which makes a GUI (Cocoa) with some text and a button...

See: [screenshot][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOzHD.png

I compile with the following command (the code is in ta.m):
gcc ta.m -o prog  -framework Cocoa -framework Foundation -framework AppKit

See the code of ta.m : http://c-studio.freevar.com/ta.txt

Is it possible to make a 'eventhandler' for the button(in one file(ta.m))?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't set an target for your button. In addition to calling `setAction:`, you need to call `setTarget:` and pass it an instance of an object that takes the `-md:` selector, which in this case would be an instance of `md` (this is a terrible class name, by the way; consider making it something more descriptive. Also, the convention is to start all class names with an upper-case letter).

Also: Consider compiling with ARC turned on; it'll make your life much easier.